# django make complex queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am writing an app where I have a house with many family in it and just one of Fathers or Mothers is head of house:

```
class House(models.Model):
    ....
    def get_head_of_house(self)
    #searchs in fathers and mothers and find which one is head of house
    #and returns it
class Fathers(models.Model):
    house = models.ForiegnKey(House)
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    is_head = models.BooleanField()
    ....
class Mothers(models.Model):
    house = models.ForiegnKey(House)
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    is_head = models.BooleanField()
    ....
```

In search form, I get first name and last name of head of a house.
I want to search in fathers and mothers and select head of all houses where
form.fname is in their first_name **or** form.lname is in their last_name

The problem is where heads are in separate models and I care about matching **either** first-name **or** last-name and more important **queryset can not be filled manually**.
How can I create this query?

Answer (score 1):

You've complicated things by creating two of the same model.

Start by making a base class and inherit if really needed

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    house = models.ForiegnKey(House)
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    is_head = models.BooleanField()

class Father(Parent):
    pass

class Mother(Parent):
    pass
```

Then make your query from there

```
Parent.objects.filter(is_head=True, Q(first_name=form.fname) | Q(last_name=form.lname))
```

or perhaps (for the house)

```
self.parent_set.filter(is_head=True, Q(first_name=form.fname) | Q(last_name=form.lname))
```

---

Without the base class you'll need a couple queries

```
def get_head_of_house(self):
    fathers = self.fathers_set.filter(is_head=True, Q(first_name=form.fname) | Q(last_name=form.lname))
    mothers = self.mothers_set.filter(is_head=True, Q(first_name=form.fname) | Q(last_name=form.lname))

    if fathers.exists():
        return fathers  # or perhaps fathers.first()

    if mothers.exists():
        return mothers  # or perhaps mothers.first()

    return None
```

Comment: Note: You could do this by querying both fathers and mothers... I just think that wouldn't be as optimal.

Comment: @ first I used a parents class with gender field. children has a mother and a father and It was an error to have two foreignkey to parents in childs models so i separated them :)

Comment: @NaserHamidi - I'd imagine a `ManyToManyField` between child and parent would resolve any issue there.. although having a base class wouldn't affect any solution you did implement there since you will still keep your fk's to Father and Mother

Comment: I changed model as above now I recive error : **You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'parents_ptr' to fathers without a default**. I do not have that field so django makes that. what should I do

Comment: @NaserHamidi - It would seem as though changing the base class is resulting in a few changes that woud be difficult to explain how to fix quickly.... If you're not too far into the project, I'd consider making a new Father/Mother class and then change all the references over to use this (since it is a single instance and not plural anyway). If its too late for that then I'd abandon the idea and I'll update my answer without the base class